# Jax RS not converting List to JSON instead throw an 500 status message

Tags: java, json, rest, jax-rs

I'm converting my data through REST protocol with JAX RS. I have a lot of working functionality already but I can't seem to convert the following thing:

**Function im calling**

```
public List<Tweet> search(String input) {
    ArrayList<Tweet> foundTweets = new ArrayList<Tweet>();
    for(int i = 1; i <= this.tweets.size(); i++){
        if(this.find(new Long(i)).getContent().contains(input)){
            foundTweets.add(this.tweets.get(i));
        }
    }
    return foundTweets;
}
```

**This throws an 500 error status code**

```
@POST
@Path("/search")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public List<Tweet> searchTweets(){
    return tweetService.searchTweets("content"); // this contains 10 items in list
}
```

**But this works for example**

```
@POST
@Path("/getAll")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public List<Tweet> searchTweets(){
    return tweetService.getAll(); // returns list of tweets
}
```

I'm quite confused right now. The search method is not available in my Tweet model. This might be one of the reasons? First time I work with JAX RS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line added Tweets but these tweets were all null. So I changed my code a bit and now everything works correctly.

```
foundTweets.add(this.tweets.get(i));
```